# certain VBA keywords (Add, Format) can't capitalize properly in VBE (As if I declared it as variable)

Tags: excel, vba, office365, code-formatting, macos-monterey

I was writing my code as usual, until suddenly I realized that certain keywords (so far, it is `add` and `format`) that won't capitalize properly after entering the line, as if it was set as variable name, (which I didn't.)

Selecting the keyword to find the definition also would not lead to any variable, just the `Object Browser`.

```
SHEET1.LISTOBJECTS(1).LISTROWS.ADD 'before going to next line [Enter] 
Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add 'The expected case change (like `Proper` function)
Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows.add 'The `add` keyword won't budge for me
```

```
DEBUG.? FORMAT(NOW,"YYYY") 'before going to next line [Enter] 
Debug.Print Format(Now,"YYYY") 'The expected case change and auto-complete of default value
Debug.Print format(Now,"YYYY") 'The `format` keyword won't budge for me.
```

I checked all the subroutines, in `ThisWorkbook`, each `WorkSheet`, each `Module` including those in `Personal.xlsb`, There was nothing that resembles `add` and `format` wording in the `Names Manager` or `lambda/let function` too. Neither was Automator/Shortcuts/Script Editors.

Even after moving out the codes (cutting all codes on a text file), the same still happens, which is impossible. ChatGPT recommended deleting `VBE6.DAT` file. But I am really curious about what else could have caused it? Or is it just another known bug for running Excel 365 on a Mac?

Please help to suggest a more suitable title if you think it is inappropriate enough, I couldn't think of one (Google certainly cant interpret the way I described it, to the extent that I need to start a post here)

Comment: Does the project compile? Do you have MISSING references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have declared them without capitals elsewhere. You can do this by declaring a variable or method (function, sub, property).

If you can't find "add" declared anywhere in your project, try adding a temporary declaration such as `Dim Add` and then removing it. You should see all your other Add methods capitalise.

Comment: Got to say, OMG I feel so stupid now, I even reinstalled Excel, without thinking of this first. 

Still, it is really odd that after adding `Dim Add, Format` line and removing it, the capitalization style remains. i.e. If I initialized `Dim aDD, FoRmAt` and removing it, the keyword would have been capitalized this way going forward. Maybe yet another unsolvable bug of Office 365 on Mac.